# On rerender, props of parent component are being disregarded for props of child component?

Tags: reactjs

Apologies in advance that this isn't a specific coding question, but I find this to be an odd bug and I am likely breaking some react principle here to be getting this, but I am not sure what's being done wrong.

Also full reproducible example is tough to do here, but here's the jist of the problem - in react, I have a graph component (d3assistnets) that generates an SVG and also renders a child table component (AssistNetTable). The render for the graph component looks like this:

```
... 
...
render() {
    const { svgID, assistNetData } = this.props;
    console.log('this.props d3assistnet: ', this.props);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Col xs={7}>
                <svg id={svgID} style={{ padding: '0' }}>
                    <g className='links' />
                    <g className='nodes' />
                </svg>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={5}>
                <AssistNetTable
                    tableData={assistNetData.links}
                />
            </Col>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

The name of the graph component is d3assistnets, and this component is passed 4 props, 2 of which are svgID and assistNetData as seen in the render. However, here is what the console.log() of `this.props` looks like:

[image]
...for some odd reason, the `this.props` on the parent d3assistnets component becomes the `tableData` object on re-render of the d3assistnets component, which is the props passed to the child `AssistNetTable` component!

When I remove AssistNetTable from the render of d3assistnets, the this.props console.log'd are **no longer weirded up** - they remain svgID, assistNetData, etc. as expected.

I've double checked the AssistNetTable component, and there is no state-setting or anything of that nature going on - it simply takes the `tableData` prop and renders a table with it. There are no console.logs in AssistNetTable as well.

Why is the `this.props` object on the parent component is being changed to the `tableData` object only is beyond my reasoning... Maybe I am breaking a react rule somewhere? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** when I change the `tableData` props to the spread operator with the parent props:

```
<AssistNetTable
    {...this.props} 
/>
```

...it freezes my browser, and the console is rapidly filled up with the console.logs() of `this.props d3assistnets`, so it looks like there's a forever loop going on here... I'm not quite sure what is calling the infinite re-renders, as AssistNetTable does not do any stateSetting, but I guess I have to dig into that. I am not sure if the infinite re-rendering is related to the parent props changing...

**Edit2:** I may just combine the 2 components into 1, as its not a lot of code and they make some sense together...

Comment: Can you include some of the code inside `AssistNetTable`'s `render` function?

Comment: According to your current codes, there's no bug or issue. Give me some more details.